# Fn address not getting available

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, windbg

I am trying to debug my demo application (windows forms) to corrupt a specific function in  memory.

I attach my app to windbg; fetch the address of a function (some button click, through x command) and put an unresolved breakpoint (bu) there.

But I'm unable to activate this breakpoint, as my function address does not become available;
Even if I run my application and call that function through the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should set an address breakpoint so use `bp` instead of `bu` so like this:

```
bp 12345678
```

where `12345678` is the address output by `x`, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff538903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).